# Pythonic idiom for checking the validity of a (negative) array index

Tags: python

My function splits a string to lines, checks the index-th line, and returns one of two values. Here's a simplified version:

```
def f(text, index):
   rows = text.split('\n')
   row = rows[index] # <-- IndexError thrown here.
   if row_meets_some_condition:
      return "Yes"
   else:
      return "No"
```

The caller sometimes passes a negative value for `index` (when he wants to use end-of-file-based-indexing), which works fine, unless `text` haw too few lines, in which case I get an `IndexError` at the `row = rows[index]` line.

Is there an idiomatic way to check that `index` is a legal index into `rows`, other than catching the error?

Comment: I'd return True/False and let the caller handle the strings. Something like `("no", "yes")[f(args)]` if you wanted to get tricky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catching an `IndexError` is pretty idiomatic in Python. If you cannot foresee how many lines your input has, you can either check the length of `rows` before accessing the list or just catch the `IndexError`. I'd go for the second option then.

Answer (score 3):

Catching `IndexError` is the idiomatic way. If this reads ugly to you, you can break it out into a separate function.

```
def validIndex(container, index):
     try:
         container[index]
     except IndexError:
         return False
     else:
         return True
```

Another way is with an `if` statement, of course:

```
if index < 0 and index < -len(rows):
     # invalid index
```

A final alternative is to just let the indexing operation fail and raise `IndexError`, putting the responsibility of ensuring the index is valid (or handling the error) on the caller. If the caller is passing you a chunk of text and a line index, then getting an exception if they pass an invalid index is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: That condition will miss indices that are too big, which the OP presumably also cares about. A better way might be: `abs(index) > len(rows)`, although that still misses an index that is exactly `len(rows)`; perhaps `not -len(rows) <= index < len(rows)`?

Comment: True. I didn't include that because I felt it was obvious how to check that.  :-)